# Преобразование кодировок строк из Web-формы

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Помогите решить проблемку с кодировками. Имеем Python 3.2, на котором написан скрипт обрабатывающий данные, полученные из формы. Данные просто сохраняются в базе данных Postgres.

Вот кусок кода формы:

```
"form1" action = "/cgi-bin/add_dolz.py" method ="GET">
            Наименование: <input type = "text" name = "d_name"><br>
            Тарифный разряд: <inp ut type = "text" name = "d_razr">
<br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Добавить">
```

Вот кусок скрипта обрабатывающий форму: (Python 3.2)

```
def Main():

    # Получаем пераметры скрипта
    f = cgi.FieldStorage()
    a  = f["d_name"].value
    b  = f["d_razr"].value

    # Формируем запрос на добавление строки в таблицу
    quer = "INSERT INTO DOLZ(NAME,RAZR) VALUES ('%s',%s)" % (a,b)

    # Подсоединяемся к серверу
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, database=DBASE,user=USER,password=PASS)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # Выполняем запрос
    cur.execute(quer)

    # Сохраняем результаты запроса в БД
    conn.commit()

    # Закрываем соединения с БД
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    # Формируем ответную html страницу
    thepage = '''<html>
                <head>
                 <title>Сообщение</title>
                 </head>
                <body>Результаты сохранены в БД PostgreSQL</body>
                </html>'''

    # отправляем страницу на сервер
    PrintPage(thepage)

# ********************************************************
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Когда я в форму ввожу данные в английской раскладке - все отрабатывается нормально. Данные сохраняются в базе данных.

Когда ввожу поля кириллицей - в браузере вылетает такая ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "c:shttpswwwcgi-binadd_dolz.py",
> line 68, in Main() File
> "c:shttpswwwcgi-binadd_dolz.py",
> line 45, in Main cur.execute(quer)
> File "C:Program FilesPython
> 3.2.1libencodingscp1251.py", line 12, in encode return
> codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec
> can't encode characters in position
> 37-41: character maps to

Я так понимаю, что данные из формы поступают в кодировке cp1251, их надо как-то преобразовать в unicode, перед тем, как записывать в базу данных??

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно указать

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

в блоке `<head>` страницы с формой

Comment: Данный вариант работает прекрасно, кириллица сохраняется в БД, однако в браузере наименования полей и кнопочек отображаются абракадаброй...�������� ������

Как-то надо средствами питона конвертить строки..

Comment: Смените редактор на поддерживающий набор в кодировке UTF-8 или проверьте текущую кодировку текста скрипта. Нужна "UTF-8 без BOM" (UTF-8 without BOM) или просто UTF-8.

Comment: укажите кодировку, если она не указана. На первой или на второй строчке: `# coding: utf-8`. Есть ещё вариант `import sys; reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")`.

Comment: Т.е. сам текст скрипта (страницы HTML) у Вас набран в cp1251 потому при установленном мета-теге с кодировкой UTF-8 браузер пытается отобразить то что набрано в cp1251 как UTF-8, 3-й же питон работает с UTF-8 строками и браузер отдаёт строки в таком формате, т.к. указали это в мета-теге. Осталось только сконвертировать сам текст скрипта в нужную кодировку (UTF-8).

Comment: qnub, спасибо, заработало. Называется дело было не в бабине...

Comment: Рад, что помог! Пометьте мой ответ как правильный, пожалуйста.